# Selecting a pair of values X-Y from two tables X-Z and Y-Z only when for every Z paired with Y it is also paired with X in the first table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Sorry for the confusing title, but I couldn't word it better.

I have two tables - `Tags` and `TagGroups`. The first has the following contents:

```
P1|a
P1|b
P1|c
P2|a
P2|c
```

And the second the following:

```
1|b
1|c
2|a
2|c
2|d
```

Letters represent tags of content P1 and P2, numbers represent groups of those tags. What I want to do is get a pair of 'content'-'tag group' where the content contains *all* tags in a given group. For the tables above, that would be just `P1|1` - P2 doesn't match 1 due to not having b, P1 and P2 don't match 2 due to not having d.

How can I do it? Or, if it's impossible/unfeasible, how can I restructure my data structure to achieve this?

Comment: Mysql or Sqlite? remove irrelevant  tag please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      t.content
           ,g.group_id   

from                    tags        as t

            join        taggroups   as g

            on          g.tag =
                        t.tag

group by    t.content
           ,g.group_id 

having      count(*) = 
            (select count(*) from taggroups as g2 where g2.group_id = g.group_id)               
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of a relational division query

```
CREATE TABLE `Tags` (
    `Cont`  TEXT,
    `Tag`   TEXT
);
insert into Tags (Cont, Tag)
values ("P1","a"),("P1","b"),("P1","c"),("P2","a"),("P2","c");

CREATE TABLE `TG` (
    `Grp`   INTEGER,
    `Tag`   TEXT
);
insert into TG (Grp, Tag)
values (1,"b"),(1,"c"),(2,"a"),(2,"c"),(2,"d");

Select c.Cont, g.Grp
from
   (select distinct Cont from Tags) c
join 
   (select distinct Grp from TG) g
on not exists (select 1 
               from TG g1
               where g1.Grp=g.Grp
                   and not exists (select 1 
                                   from Tags c1
                                   where c1.Cont=c.Cont
                                       and g1.Tag=c1.Tag)
                );
```